Indie movie where missing girl comes back as a werewolf
Okay, this was an indie movie I saw on American Netflix a couple of years ago (I want to say 2014), but can't remember the title. 
It took place in a very wealthy neighborhood, I'm guessing maybe in the New England area or possibly upstate New York. This one family has a daughter in college who is home on break. She goes out for a run after dinner one night and vanishes. Some time passes, I think about a year, then she shows up at her parents home in the middle of the night crying hysterically and covered in dirt. She has no memory of where she's been.
After she returns the neighbors start getting killed off, apparently having been attacked by a wild animal. The big twist is that her father was involved in some kind of shady business with the neighbors, and they killed her, so she actually came back from the dead as a werewolf. I hope this description is helpful. I'd really like to see this movie again.

Can we get a number for how long ago? And I'm assuming American netflix?

American Netflix I want to say 2014.

Are you absolutely sure she's a werewolf?

Any clues to how old the movie was?

I think the movie was made in the early 2000s maybe 2003, or 2004. I'm pretty sure that she was able to transform into a  werewolf, or similar creature when she made the kills.
